# Using Jquery inside wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i have a plugin that contain a function to insert/get data from DB .
my question is how can i use jquery or link any other JS inside wordpress plugin  .
i search and found many article but it is not clear , please i nead steps to add jquery file in my plugin.
belw steps i tried 
add this lines at top of my page .

its is my plugin code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: myplugin
Description: form
Version: 4.0
Author: hercal
License: GPL
*/
?>
<?php 
function  form_creation()
{
global $wpdb;
function my_scripts_method()
{
wp_enqueue_script('fn',plugins_url('/myplugin/fn.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'jquery' )
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
?>
<form action=" <?php get_permalink(); ?> " method="post" id="myform">
<table>


<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="txtname" name="txtname" placeholder="Your Name"/> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<!-- drop down menu  (Country )-->
<select id='select_Country' name="select_Country" >
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> -- Select Country -- </option>
        <?php
        $query='select Code,Country from _country order by Country';
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        foreach( $result as $row ) 
        {
           echo '<option value='.$row->Code.'>'.$row->Country.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select> 

</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<!-- drop down menu  (City )-->
<select id="select_city" name="select_city">
    <option selected="selected"> -- Select City -- </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td> <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" name='submit'/> </td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<?php } ?>
<?php
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $name=strip_tags($_POST['txtname']);
    $country=$_POST['select_Country'];
    $city=$_POST['select_city'];
    $insertQuery="insert into _customers(Name,Country,City)values('$name','$country','$city')";
    $wpdb->query($insertQuery);
}
?>
<?php add_shortcode('test',form_creation); ?>
```

and below is fn.js which located in C:\wamp\www\test\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\fn.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    <!-- ajax method to bind the dropdown menu of model-->
        $("#select_brand").change(function(){
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "model.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#select_Model").html(data);
        } 
        });
        });

    <!-- ajax method to bind the dropdown menu of city-->   
        $("#select_Country").change(function(){
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "city.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("yes");
            $("#select_city").html(data);
        } 
        });
        });
        });
</script>
```

and finally the code of city.php

```
<?php
    if($_POST['id'])
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $query="select id,CountryCode,City from _city where CountryCode='$id'";
        $result=$wpdb->get_results($query);
        echo '<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> -- Select City -- </option>';
        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
            $id=$row->id;
            $city=$row->city;
            echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$city.'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
```

the problem is City dropdown can't get values .

Comment: It sounds like jQuery is being enqueued just fine. Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: when i press control+Shift+J in console browser.
and the code is not working

Comment: @webeno , i already read it but some points not clear

Comment: @Hercal2020 i already removed my comment... ;)

Comment: It sounds like a JavaScript error, not a PHP error.

Comment: Try it with filter: `add_filter('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_init');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Using

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

To Enqueue Script in your plugin file

Example

```
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'jsscript',
    plugins_url( '/js/jsscript.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'jquery' )
  );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

link- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: also not work , i will post my code , please check it , tell me why it is not working .

Comment: hey plz enqueue my_scripts_method() function outside  the form_creation() function i thing it will work fine

Comment: done but same problem , it can't find the file fn.js , when i press f12 ->resources , i found the file name only but it contain no code

Comment: Okk got it change plugins_url('/myplugin/fn.js' , __FILE__ ) to  plugins_url('myplugin/fn.js' , __FILE__ ) it will work. and put your js file within myplugin folder

Comment: also, if you move this part out of your file, the 2nd parameter (`FILE`) might need to be changed, depending on where moved that code bit, more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: it now can reach fn.js but gives an error when post to  city.php , Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Hercal2020 you're way over the realms of this one question, please choose a right answer then move on to a new one...

Comment: @webeno , ok , sorry for disturbance

Comment: @Hercal2020 there isn't any disturbance, it's just the way of things around here :)

Answer (score 2):

You are clearly including another custom script / js file somewhere else in your wordpress implementation but are not making it dependant on jQuery, therefore it's being run before jQuery would be loaded. So make sure your custom script containing jQuery code is made dependant from it.

See below (make note of `array('jquery')` within the function):

```
<?php

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

?>
```

Source: [Function Reference/wp enqueue script - Link a Theme Script Which Depends on jQuery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery)

Comment: also not work , i will post my code , please check it , tell me why it is not working